# bash: line 146: [: missing `] - Gitlab CI/CD

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, gitlab

guys so I'm trying to make this if statement inside the script part of my CI/CD but it's giving a `bash: line 146: [: missing` ]` error which I'm not sure why is happening.

My script in CI/CD:

```
script:
        - >
            if [ $CI_COMMIT_TAG && $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME =~ /^v/ ]; then 
                sshpass -e ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $DOCKER_SSH_USERNAME@$DOCKER_MACHINE "cd /home/$DOCKER_SSH_USERNAME && git clone $GIT_CLONE_URL && cd qcast-vosk-stt/ && chmod +x deploy.sh && ./deploy.sh -i $INSTANCES -e PRODUCTION";
                echo "Inside";
            else 
                sshpass -e ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $DOCKER_SSH_USERNAME@$DOCKER_MACHINE "cd /home/$DOCKER_SSH_USERNAME && git clone $GIT_CLONE_URL && cd qcast-vosk-stt/ && chmod +x deploy.sh && ./deploy.sh -i $INSTANCES -e DEVELOPMENT"; 
                echo "Elsed";
            fi
```

The pipeline error:

```
$ if [ $CI_COMMIT_TAG && $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME =~ /^v/ ]; then  # collapsed multi-line command
/usr/bin/bash: line 146: [: missing `]'
```

Comment: it should be `if [ condition1 ] && [ condition2 ]; then command1; else command2; fi`. So you shoul put a `]` before `&&` and also put a consistent check to variable `$CI_COMMIT_TAG`

Comment: this is not what's wrong, single `[ ]` does not support binary operator `=~`. You have to use `[[ ]]`, it's perfectly fine to use `[[ $a && $b =~ pattern ]]` and  `/ /` should be remove if they are not part of the pattern

Comment: @bac0n this worked :)

Answer (score 0):

```
[[ $CI_COMMIT_TAG && $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME =~ /^v/ ]];
```

should fix the problem. I don't see any issues with that warning, but it's always good to fix.